# Is my 'transitioned' event listener not working?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm expecting the top paragraph to fade out as the bottom paragraph fades in but the element is getting removed from the DOM before the animation happens.

When there are 5 paragraphs in the collection (querySelectorAll) the 0 index gets removed. The CSS animation works as expected for createElement not for .remove()

What am I missing?

```js
function addPara() {
  let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
  let g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
  let b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
  let bg = `#${r}${g}${b}`
  let qsaPara = document.querySelectorAll('p');
  const para = document.createElement('p')
  para.style.backgroundColor = bg
  para.style.height = '3rem'
  document.body.appendChild(para)
  let paraArray = Array.from(qsaPara);
  let l = paraArray.length
  let clVal = para.classList.value;

  function parRemove() {
    paraArray[0].remove();
    paraArray[0].removeEventListener('transitionend', parRemove)
  }


  if (paraArray.length >= 5) {
    paraArray[0].classList.add('fall');
    // para.innerHTML += `class:${clVal}`

    paraArray.forEach((para, i) => {
      para.nextSibling.innerHTML = `index ${i}, collection length${l}, class:${clVal}`;
    });

          //------------------------
    paraArray[0].addEventListener('transitionend', parRemove, false);
    //----------------------

  } else if (paraArray.length <= 5) {
    paraArray.forEach((para, i) => {
      para.innerHTML = `index ${i}, collection length${l}, class:${clVal}`
    })
  }

}

const paraTimer = setInterval(addPara, 2000);
```

```css
p {
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  animation-name: fade-in;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  transition: all ease-in-out 1s;
}

.fade {
  animation-name: fade-out;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

@keyframes fade-in {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fade-out {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Try waiting ~50 milliseconds before adding the transitionend event listener

Comment: `addEventListener` takes a function name, currently you're calling it immediately. `paraArray[0].addEventListener('transitionend', parRemove(), false);`

Comment: When i change to parRemove it ignores the condition

Comment: @Rojo how would you suggest ?     setTimeout(paraArray[0].addEventListener('transitionend', parRemove, false), 50) didnt help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842255/transitionend-event-doesnt-fire-when-my-animation-finishes

Comment: https://jonsuh.com/blog/detect-the-end-of-css-animations-and-transitions-with-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue with transitionend expecting CSS transform and NOT animation.

Use webkitAnimationEnd / animationend event listeners for css animations and use webkitTransitionEnd / 'transitionend' event listeners for css transform transitions.

If ya didn't know, well now ya know.

I updated the answer with a fix for my original animation

```js
 function addPara() {
   let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
   let g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
   let b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
   let bg = `#${r}${g}${b}`
   let qsaPara = document.querySelectorAll('p');
   const para = document.createElement('p')
   para.style.backgroundColor = bg
   para.style.height = '3rem'
   document.body.appendChild(para)
   let paraArray = Array.from(qsaPara);
   let l = paraArray.length
   let clVal = para.classList.value;

   function parRemove() {
     
     paraArray[0].remove()
    // paraArray[0].removeEventListener('transitionend', parRemove)
    
    paraArray[0].removeEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", parRemove);
    paraArray[0].removeEventListener("animationend", parRemove, false);


   }

   if (paraArray.length >= 5) {
     paraArray.forEach((para, i) => {
       para.nextSibling.innerHTML = `index ${i}, collection length${l}`;


   // for css transition
   /*        paraArray[0].classList.add('fall');
          paraArray[0].addEventListener('transitionend', parRemove, false) */

   // for css animation
   paraArray[0].classList.add('fade');
   paraArray[0].addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', parRemove, false); // Code for Chrome, Safari and Opera
   paraArray[0].addEventListener("animationend", parRemove, false);
 });

    



   } else if (paraArray.length <= 5) {
     paraArray.forEach((para, i) => {
       para.innerHTML = `index ${i}, collection length${l}`
     })
   }
 }

 const paraTimer = setInterval(addPara, 2000);
```

```css
p {
  opacity: 1;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  animation-name: fade-in;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  /* transition: all ease-in-out 1s; */
}

 .fade {
  animation-name: fade-out;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
} 

@keyframes fade-in {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fade-out {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
  /*
   .fall {
  transform: scale(3);
  transform: translateY(9rem);
  opacity: 0;
}. */
```